# IDENTITY is red underlined while trying to create a table in SQL

Tags: java, sql, identity

I'm a Java student and I was trying to create a table for my database web app project.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name varchar(45),
  last_name varchar(45),
  email varchar(45),
 
  );
```

So I used `IDENTITY(1,1)` to get the `id` start from `1` and `auto increment` by `1`. But `IDENTITY` is underlined and I do not know why. Also when I try to run the code I get this Output :

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id int IDENTITY(1,1),
  first_name varchar(45),
  last_name varchar(45),
  email varchar(45),
 
  )
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple syntax errors.  But the code you want is:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name varchar2(45),
    last_name varchar2(45),
    email varchar2(45)
);
```

Notes:

- The syntax in Oracle is different from SQL Server.  There are no arguments to `IDENTITY` and you want `GENERATED ALWAYS AS` for the column.
- Oracle prefers `VARCHAR2()` to `VARCHAR()`.
- You have missing and extra commas.
- 45 characters seems too short for the columns, particularly the email.
- I prefer table names in the plural because they contain multiple copies of an entity.

Comment: I just realized my Oracle is not 12c. so IDENTITY column does not exist at all.

Comment: @Kelise It would be more useful to know which version you *do* have, instead of just knowing it is not 12c.

Comment: @Kelise . . . In that case, you need to use a sequence and probably a trigger.

Comment: @Andreas IDENTITY column was added after 12c so that's why I said it's not 12c but FYI mine is 11g.

Comment: @Kelise "not 12c" could also mean "18c" or "19c" instead of "11g", which is why being clear on what you *do* have is more important than telling us what you don't have.